# Samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300): Wiped Download mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, odin

Something went badly wrong while trying to flash my phone. I have somehow managed to delete Odin/Download mode. I CAN access ClockworkMod, but it's a very old version not supported by the ROM I wanted to use. I cannot access download mode.

Is there any way I can update ClockworkMod and/or restore Odin?

Galaxy i9300

Comment: I didn't even know it was possible to delete Odin mode...

Comment: You may have soft-bricked your device if Download mode is not available. Since you have a SGS3, a USB Jig won't help as it only work on Gingerbread and earlier Android versions. Try taking out the phone's battery, then boot into Download mode by holding down Volume Down + Home + Power keys, and while holding down these buttons (ask someone if you can't yourself) put the battery back in the device. Wait until you see the Download mode before releasing the buttons. If you still don't see it, then you have hard-bricked your device. You need to take it back to the reseller and get it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to now have some kind of download mode, though it's not the Samsung one - I just flashed a new ROM. Going to close this either way, as I don't think there's a simple solution other than sending it back.

Answer (score 0):

An S-BOOT clip can restore your phone in download mode.

[image]

Comment: I have i9300 water damaged no light at all (dead) but i managed to put it in DL mode by inserting this S-Boot Clip. If your phone stuck in DL mode you have to flash it and then repair IMEI by z3x box.